# Assembly return a pointer using malloc

Tags: c, pointers, assembly

I'm just practicing assembly with coprocessor. The thing is I don't know how to return pointer to my value.

The code in C:

```
double * distance(float x, float y, float z);
```

And my Assembly code:

```
    .code

_distance  PROC
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, 0
    finit ; some aritmetic
    fldz
    fld dword PTR [ebp + 8]
    fsubp st(1), st(0)
    fmul st(0), st(0) ; 0 - x

    fldz
    fld dword PTR [ebp + 12]
    fsubp st(1), st(0)
    fmul st(0), st(0)

    fldz
    fld dword PTR [ebp + 16]
    fsubp st(1), st(0)
    fmul st(0), st(0)

    faddp st(1), st(0)
    faddp st(1), st(0)

    fsqrt

    push 10 ; first i push 10 bytes for malloc                                       
    call _malloc 
    add esp, 4 
    fstp [eax], st(0) ; and then i want to point to the specific value

    pop ebp
    ret
_distance  ENDP
```

As far as i know malloc allocates memory and returns the address in eax. So the only thing I want to know how to point to the value of cooprocessor register and return it.

Comment: Just return eax which already points to the memory you just allocated with malloc. BTW why do you allocate 10 bytes ? Usually the size of a double is 8. And why do you need to allocate memory at all ? Just return a double value instead of a pointer to a double.

Comment: Another suggestion: write your code in C and look at the compiler's assembly output.

Comment: I allocate 10 bytes because coprocessor register is 80 bits therefore there is 10 bytes. 

I'll try. Didn't know that it is possible to write C code and see how it looks like in assembly. :)

Comment: OK I see, Which compiler/developement environnment do you use ?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: To see the assembly code: debug step by step, then you can open the disassembly window with Debug->Windows->Disassembly.

Comment: Alright, it works!
I had to change  fstp [eax], st(0) to fstp dword PTR [eax]
Does anyone know why dword PTR is needed to do it?
Michael Walz- thank you very very much

Comment: Because `fstp` comes in 3 operand sizes and you need to tell the assembler which one you want or else it might pick a default that you won't like ;)